# What software to use when playing online?

Tags: online, poker-tools, software

I want to use some software for online play that would help with better information about my opponents. I think I saw over the years some screenshots with such software, but I don't know their name.

What this software should do is show next to each player some information such as how many times that player called, raised, checked etc., the AF, PFR etc. I really don't know what to add to this list...

I suspect that such software works only on certain poker platforms. I play mostly on PokerStars and on PartyPoker.

If you know of any such software that works with these platforms, please tell me. Thank you.

**Edit**: I found [Poker Tracker](http://www.pokertracker.com/). Do you know of anything similar ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty much quoting my [answer to a very similar question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/652/22):

> There are two major players in this field: [Hold'em Manager](http://www.holdemmanager.com) and [Poker Tracker](http://www.pokertracker.com). Both provide the type of in-depth number crunching and statistical analysis/display that you're looking for. They track things that few players would even think to look at without first seeing the information available in one of these two programs.
>
> In my experience, Hold'em Manager has a wider array of options for cash games, giving it a slight edge there. They even have some plugins that can detect strange patterns in your opponent's play and automatically issue notes about those plays. However, something about the way Hold'em Manager imports tournament results is messed up, so that gives Poker Tracker the edge for tournaments.

Comment: +1. Thanks. I didn't know there was a lot of such real-time software.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeff. This pair of SW are often cited as the best ones (and most popular). But they are closed source and payed SW and I'll like to extend OP question to Open Software. In your experience, there are any good enogh ?

Answer (score 6):

There are a *lot* of such software but only a few of them are good.

Note that there are limitations as to what sites do accept.  For example on Cake Poker --but this is an extreme case-- HUDs aren't allowed.  They obfuscate on purpose the names of your ennemies in the hand histories to make sure tracker do not work, besides for tracking your own results.

But that's an extreme case: typically trackers & HUDs are welcome.

It usually goes like this:

- everything that analyze *past deals* is allowed
- everything that analyze the current deal is forbidden

For example PokerStars makes it very clear that you *cannot* use a software that suggest you to *fold/call/raise*.  For example imagine a software that would recognize that you have 72o preflop UTG and would say: *"I suggest you fold"* or, worse, a bot that would automatically click on "fold" for you... Well, that is forbidden.

Pokerstars keeps a list of prohibited software.  It used to be at:

www.pokerstars.com/poker/room/prohibited/

So make sure you're not using a prohibited software: the PokerStars client does check what's installed on your computer to make sure nobody is cheating.

*(as I'm writing this from France I cannot easily verify if that URL is still valid because I'm redirected to PokerStars.fr automatically).*

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look on this list:
http://www.pokerlistings.com/analysis-software
I think you'll find some software that suits you.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will go through that list. PS: We're from the same city :) .

Comment: Yes, I saw you were a rat :-". I never used such a program but from reading the descriptions Sit & Go Shark seemed the best. I don't think there's a free version though.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Mac, there is [Poker Copilot](http://pokercopilot.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I would give it a shot to holdem indicator and tournament indicator. Quite simple and clear!

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Android, you may like "All-In Poker Tracker" app

Comment: Why? and do you have a link to it?