# What is the best poker tracker/software?

Tags: software, pokertracker, holdem-manager

I'm looking for a good poker tracker to improve my game.

I found already this old [article](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/29/news-views-gossip/top-5-best-poker-software-programs-improve-your-game-1000754/) at the 2+2 forum from 2010:

> Hand HQ
>
> *Best Supplemental Program*
>
> Website: www.handhq.com 
>   Price: Starts at around $10 and increases as more hand histories are purchased.
>   Free Trial: No
>   Type: Hand History Database
>   Score: A (when used in conjunction with a tracker program)
>   Data mined hand histories that can be used and uploaded into analysis
>   programs like Poker Tracker or Hold’ Em Manager. This is not software
>   you have to download, you purchase a certain amount of hand histories
>   and for a small price receive them in a zip file. Great information
>   for a low price, but didn’t get an A+ because it’s only most useful
>   when used with another program.
>
> Poker Crusher
>
> *Best Opponent Profiler*
>
> Website: www.pokercrusher.com
>   Price: Varies. Starts at $5-$30 a month depending on the plan you buy.
>   Free Trial: No.
>   Type: Poker Tracker, Analytics, HUD, Profiling
>   Score: B+
>   This is great analysis software to
>   give you stats on how your opponents play. The Poker Crusher stats
>   database is comprehensive and using this software will show you a ton
>   of stats on Pre-Flop, Flop, Turn, River and Showdown play, breaking up
>   player statistics so you can see what your opponent has done in each
>   situation in the past. This in depth analysis may not be as helpful,
>   but confusing for new players as the HUD lays out these stats in a way
>   that will require knowledge of the online poker landscape to
>   understand. However, if you’re seeking a comprehensive profile of the
>   people you play, this program is a great option.
>
> Hold’Em Manager
>
> *Most User Friendly*
>
> Website: www.holdemmanager.com
>   Price: $89.99 for the Pro Version (Most common)
>   Free Trial: Yes, a 15 day trial is available.
>  
>   Type: Poker Tracker, Analytics, HUD, Profiling
>   Score: A-
>   The depth of information combined with the general usability of this program is why we rated Hold ‘Em Manager well. Like many other poker analysis tools, the
>   breadth of information covered is wide, but with Hold ‘Em Manager you
>   do not have to be an expert to understand how to review and analyze
>   your playing. This makes this program more compatible with beginners
>   while still be valuable to experts. Another great thing is it’s
>   “Player Summary” area where you can make notes and analyze stats on
>   your opponents. I’m not sure what else you could ask for in a poker
>   analysis tool and HUD.
>
> Poker Tracker 3
>
> *Best Comprehensive Program* Available for Mac
>
> Website: www.pokertracker.com
>   Price: $89.99 for Full Version
>   Free Trial: Yes, 60 day free trial is available.
>   Type: Poker Tracker, Analytics, HUD
>   Score: A
>   One of the great things about this program is that it’s available on a free 60-day trial AND has a Mac version. The automated installation makes it friendly for beginners who may not want to deal with or know how to handle a manual install, like many pieces of poker software have. It’s also a customizable program so while the default settings and reports will be helpful, you can change the settings so that the HUD and reports can give you the information that you’re looking for. For more advanced users, Poker Tracker 3 also has a customizable statistics engine where you can create your own stats that you can even add to the HUD. The only thing Poker Tracker doesn’t have is an easy poker profiler, but if you can get used to reading the stats it provides, you’ll be able to profile people yourself in no time.
>
> Hold ‘Em Genius
>
> *Best Beginner’s Tool*
>
> Website: www.holdemgenius.com
>   Price: $99.85
>   Free Trial: No.
>   Type: Odds Calculator
>   Score: A-
>   This is a great program for what it specializes
>   in, calculating odds. If you’re looking for something a little more
>   statistics heavy like a tracker or tool for analyzing your moves post
>   play, then this may not be for you. However, there are many pluses to
>   perhaps using this tool in addition to a tracking and analytics tool.
>   Firstly, Hold ‘Em Genius is basically a skin for your poker room –
>   giving you all of the details and advice for how to play your hand as
>   flawlessly as possible. For beginners, it’s a great tool because it
>   visually shows you what your odds of winning are, and where on the
>   spectrum the value of your hand is.

and [this anwser](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/675/what-software-to-use-when-playing-online) from 2012.

Both articles are kinda old and my question is, if there are other programes that are quite as good or are Hold'em Manager and Poker Tracker still the best software I can buy?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, those two are still the best. Also, what OS are you running? there's no HM for mac.

Comment: I've both - windows and mac but most time I play on windows, so HM should be fine for me too thought.

Comment: It would be great if someone that has tested alot of those trackers could compare them here as an anwser like in 2+2 forum: http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/29/news-views-gossip/top-5-best-poker-software-programs-improve-your-game-1000754/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[HoldemManager 2](http://www.holdemmanager.com/) and [PokerTracker 4](http://www.pokertracker.com/products/PT4/) are still the market leaders.

HoldemManager 2 uses a lot of ram, especially when you play 12+tabled and use a HUD.
But when you play on MacOSx you can only use PokerTracker 4 - because Holdem Manager 2 is Windows only.

But it also depends on which stakes you play. If you only play micros and do not want to spend 100$ for tracking software, you could also use [FreePokerDB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fpdb/)

Comment: I play alot of tournaments and sometimes $0.10/$0.25 cash tables and rarely SNGs. But mainly I want improve my tournament play. Is there anything you can say about + or - of those two softwares?

Comment: as I said - for HM2 is that it is very ram-intensive, but I like the UI of HM2 more than the one from PT4. Functionality is almost the same.

Comment: Okay - so if they are almost the same it shouldn't be that big difference. Actually I'm testing the trail version of HoldemManager2.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Mac it's got to be Poker Copilot. It's really simple to use, simple to set up and they give a really decent trial period - although it costs £49 (~$80) to purchase once it's ran out, so it can be quite pricey.

I also like the PokerZebra software (available on the Mac app store for a few pounds) to calculate pot odds quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, FPDB is a great, valid, and valuable utility that is 100% and open source last time I checked. And it works just fine at sealswithclubs :)

If you want a relatively 'light' database and hand tracker/analyzer, DEFINITELY try out FPDB.

If you are looking for a highly valuable, and game changing leak buster, I suggest HoldemManager HIGHLY. Do not mistake me, I am a poker professional whose sole source of income has been internet poker, and I have used with great success (and cost, both monetary and of memory) every iteration of HUD and PTx, and while those are great to this day they don't hold a candle to the utility of http://www.holdemmanager.com/buy/4/leak-buster-no-limit

GL

-YourPokerBloke

Answer (score 2):

In January 2016:

[PokerTracker](https://www.pokertracker.com/) and [Hold'em Manager](http://www.holdemmanager.com/) still dominate. The two companies merged in late 2014, so they are now two products from the same company, with identical pricing and similar features.

[Poker Copilot](https://pokercopilot.com/) was for a long time only for Mac OS X, but since November 2015 is also for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

i just got pt4 and hm2. i am using pt4 at black chip poker and americas card room.

pt4 works seamlessly with these sites. hm2 should also, but i have not tried it yet.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Leak buster and Ace poker drills. It's a good training software.

Leak buster analyzes your game, finds leaks and helps to get rid of them.

And Ace poker drills is a poker-quiz. It places players in common pre-flop and post flop situations in a quiz style format, and provides feedback about how to improve their poker game. It also teaches people how to properly count outs and convert those outs to odds. It tracks and charts progress

Comment: He specifically asks for tracking software.  It looks like your answer is the same answer that you use for all your posts here.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Sharkscope HUD for almost 2 years and it really lacks a lot of features that aren't specific to tournaments or the sharkscope database stats. It won't offer much to detect leaks and it doesn't do much to improve your game or help exploit opponents. I was looking into PokerCopilot and it appears as this is the exact same software with the same layout and everything. I would not recommend either of those and stick with good ol' Poker Tracker 4