# Poker Tools : Recording Hands / Outcomes

Tags: texas-hold-em, betting-strategy, poker-tools

Not *really* looking for a bank manager as I've already looked at:
[Tools for Managing Bankroll, Income and Losses](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/85/tools-for-managing-bankroll-income-and-losses)

and it's not what I'm looking for.

I want to know if you guys have any tools that (preferably) automatically record my hole cards and the community cards in addition to how I bet so that I can review and analyze the plays later.

If automation is not possible, something that I can VERY quickly record this sort of information?

I play on a number of different platforms (phone, afk, client, browser(facebook)) so any tools are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking at using well known poker sites & networks (e.g. Pokerstars, iPoker, Merge, etc.) then "Pokertracker" and "Holdem manager" are likely the best software out there for this. Check [**this**](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/651/88) question.

As for recording hands from facebook poker, poker clients on the phone, and any other browser based system, i've *never* heard of any real time systems. There is the possibility you could get the provider to send you hand histories, and then import them into 3rd party software, or just review them as is.

Comment: Just trialed Pokertracker, it's exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

For situatons where automated recording is not possible, I'd recommend something like the short-hand I developed when programming the FlopTurnRiver.com Hand History Trimmer. For cash games, you'll want to replace M value with stack-sizes, and probably include that info for opponents too:

> The condensed history follows the following format:
>   [Cards] Position (M Value; action preceding user + User Action)
>
> - Cards are the cards dealt to the user.
> - Position is the position the user occupied at the table 
>     (determined by the location of the dealer button). 
>     This is one of:
>     UTG, UTG+1, UTG+2, MP1, MP2, CO-1, CO, BU, SB, BB.
> - M Value is the ratio of the user's stack to the initial pot.
>     This is calculated by dividing the user's stack by the sum of
>     blinds and antes.
> - Action preceding the user represents the action seen before the
>     user acted preflop. Actions are separated by a + sign. Each
>     action is represented by a lowercase letter: c means called,
>     f means folded, p means pushed all-in, r means raised.
> - User Action represents the action taken by the user. The same
>     translation as above applies, however the actions taken by the
>     user are represented by capitol letters.
>
> Example:
>   **[2s 3c] UTG+1 (M=50.00; r+F)**
>   means:
>   The user was dealt 2s and 3c as his down cards, was second to act, 
>     had 50 times the sum of blinds and antes, faced a raise from the 
>     player who was first to act, and chose to fold.